# Getting dimensions of all children elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm looking for the nicest way to write a component that does the following:

- Create an array of children components to render
- Render these components (Since the dimensions will be unknown until they are rendered)
- Get dimensions of each of these components
- Perform foo after all these component dimensions are received / any time these child dimensions are updated

The solution that i have so far looks like this

```
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      childDimensions:[]
    }
  } 

  getChildDimension(id, dimensions){
    const newChildDimensions = this.state.childDimensions.slice()
    newChildDimensions[id] = dimensions
    this.setState({'childDimensions': newChildDimensions})

    foo(this.state.childDimensions)
  }

  render(){
    const children = this.props.data.map((element,index)=>{
      return <Child data={element} id={index} getDim={this.getChildDimension}/>
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Issue with this is that foo() is called each time getChildDimensions is called, when ideally i only want it to run once when all child components has called getChildDimensions. Also i think that each setState call was ignoring/overriding the changes made by other getChildDimensions called.

Ideally I want a way to write this with something like a Promise.all that will run foo() once a set of dimensions has been received from every child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform foo only when then length of this.state.childDimensions is equal to the length of this.props.data ?

```
  getChildDimension(id, dimensions){
    const newChildDimensions = this.state.childDimensions.slice()
    newChildDimensions[id] = dimensions
    this.setState({'childDimensions': newChildDimensions},(state)=>{
      if(this.props.data.length === state.childDimensions.length){
        foo(state.childDimensions)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: HI Benjamin,

I think that can work for when i initially mount the component. But when the component is resized and all the children update their dimensions then i think foo will end up running once per child, which is something i am trying to avoid

Comment: Ok, so you need an eventListener on resize in your child component, and update your childDimensions on resize. then, you perform foo if this.props.data.length is equals to this.state.childDimensions.length

Comment: On resize, the corresponding index of state.childDimensions should be overridden with the new dimension, so i don't think the length of state.childDimensions will change. In that case  (this.props.data.length === this.state.childDimensions.length) will be true every time childDimensions is updated and foo will be run once per child, would it not?

Comment: Yeah, so the event listener should be on the parent component, then it will be called once per resize.

Comment: Ahh i see, yeah i think that should do it then. Thanks!